# MYSQL PREPARE EXECUTE with result wont show result

Tags: mysql

I  cant see result although I am informed there are 86 rows. I think I am missing something really easy but I can't find out what.

```
SET @sql_dynamic = (
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      ' MAX(IF(exam_id = ''',
      exam_id,
      ''', percent_correct, 0)) AS exam',
      exam_id
    ))
FROM table1);
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT usuario, ',@sql_dynamic,' FROM table1 group by usuario');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

which is the equivalent to

```
SELECT usuario, MAX(IF(exam_id = '2', percent_correct, 0)) AS exam2,
 MAX(IF(exam_id = '3', percent_correct, 0)) AS exam3,
MAX(IF(exam_id = '4', percent_correct, 0)) AS exam4,
MAX(IF(exam_id = '5', percent_correct, 0)) AS exam5,
MAX(IF(exam_id = '6', percent_correct, 0)) AS exam6,
MAX(IF(exam_id = '7', percent_correct, 0)) AS exam7
FROM table1 GROUP BY usuario
```

and these is my result:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;# MySQL ha devuelto un conjunto de valores vacío (es decir: cero columnas).
EXECUTE stmt;# Filas: 86 <---- I am getting 86 rows but doesnt show them
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;# MySQL ha devuelto un conjunto de valores vacío (es decir: cero columnas).
```

I am getting 86 rows but doesn't show them. How can I see them ? Thanks. Saving as a new table would also work.

EDIT
If i select @sql i get

```
SELECT usuario,  MAX(IF(exam_id = '2', percent_correct, 0)) AS t2, MAX(IF(exam_id = '3', percent_correct, 0)) AS t3,
MAX(IF(exam_id = '4', percent_correct, 0)) AS t4,
MAX(IF(exam_id = '5', percent_correct, 0)) AS t5,
MAX(IF(exam_id = '6', percent_correct, 0)) AS t6,
MAX(IF(exam_id = '7', percent_correct, 0)) AS t7
FROM table1 group by usuario
```

Comment: Can you produce this issue on http://rextester.com/ and provide us the link back

Comment: Can you add a print instruction for `@sql`

Comment: http://rextester.com/live/YQUW70856

Comment: If i execute the select usuario,.....    straight i see the table but not with the PREPARE stmt

Comment: Fixed http://rextester.com/live/YQUW70856

Comment: Thanks. Still same, doesnt work in my server... it says 86 rows but wont show them   EXECUTE stmt; **# Filas: 86** DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;# MySQL ha devuelto un conjunto de valores vacío (es decir: cero columnas).

Comment: Can you include the result of `analyze table1`